# Logic behind sum of rows/columns for Sudoku problem

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I'm doing practice with arrays and to code a Sudoku Checker Program I have to check the sum of rows and columns of a 9x9 matrix.

Given that the matrix is 9x9, the sum of each row/column must be 45 for the sudoku to be valid.

The easiest way would be to do something like this:

```
/*example for rows*/
for(column=0;column<9;column++){
sum0=sum0+sudoku[0][column];
sum1=sum1+sudoku[1][column];
sum2=sum2+sudoku[2][column];
sum3=sum3+sudoku[3][column];
...
/*repeat for all 9 sums and then simply check if one of the sums is != from 45
```

I don't like this code because it works only for this 9x9 fixed size sudoku.
What I'm trying to do is linking the index of sum with the index of the row; maybe using an array.

For example:

```
int sum[9];
for(column=0;column<9;column++){
sum[row]=sum[row]+sudoku[row][column]
```

The idea is that before the index of row is increased all columns must have been checked but I can't figure out the loop to do so.
Also, if after all the columns have been checked and the sum is !=45  there is no need to check for other rows as the sudoku is not valid.

That could be done with a simple code like this:

```
if(sum[row]!=45){
fail_flag=1;
}
/*then stop the loop and return fail_flag*/
```

Is this approach to the problem correct?Any suggestion on how I could setup the loop I explained?

Comment: I don't think the approach *is* the best one. The rule isn't that rows etc all sum to 45, but exactly one of each number must be present (in which case they sum to 45). The set `1 1 3 4 5 6 7 9 9` sums to 45 but is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compact way to check for lines and then column could be:

```
// First check lines
for(int line=0;line<9;line++){
  int sum=0;
  for(int column=0;column<9;column++){
    sum+=sudoku[line][column];
  }
  if(sum!=45){
   fail_flag=1;
   //Break will exit the loop
   break;
  }
}

// Then check column
if(fail_flag==0){
  for(int column=0;column<9;column++){
    int sum=0;
    for(int line=0;line<9;line++){
      sum+=sudoku[line][column];
    }
    if(sum!=45){
     fail_flag=1;
     //Break will exit the loop
     break;
    }
  }
}
```

However, in the case of Sudoku checking the sum is not enough, e.g. if you fill the grids with 5 everywhere you will get 45 for each row/col.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I'll try to implement the code so that for each row and column there can't be any duplicate values and the values can't be <0 or >10

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is that before the index of row is increased all columns must
>   have been checked but I can't figure out the loop to do so.

You can achieve this functionality with a nested for loop like this:

```
const int sudokuSize = 9
int sum[9];

int row, col;
for (row = 0; row < sudokuSize; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < sudokuSize; col++) {
        sum[row] = sum[row] + sudoku[row][column]
    }
    if (sum[row] != 45) {
        fail_flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, for validating a Sudoku Cube, it is not sufficient. You need to improve the logic by checking for occurrence of all numbers (0-9) in each row and in each column

Comment: With that code,given that the user inputs a valid sudoku, if after the loop I add this code - for (row=0;row<9;row++) and then printf("%d",sum[row]). Shouldn't I get 9 times 45 as output?

Comment: @Mizzet Yes, you will get sum of each row. If you just want to display result you will do like this: `if (fail_flag != 1) { printf("Valid Sudoku"); } else { printf("Invalid Sudoku"); }`